# Accessible CS Math Job

Tags: proof-techniques, cryptography, mathematical-programming, security

I am a CS undergrad and a huge enthusiast of pure math. I have been doing competitive programming and proofs for a while. My ambition is to become an academic in theoretical computer science. The problem I face, like any math enthusiast, is that academia pathway jobs are not reliable in terms of funding. So, I thought of getting an alternative job besides my academic career.

**First**, I have been looking for jobs in which I could utilize my mathematical curiosity. **Second**, As I am an Undergrad, I need a pathway whose beginning is accessible for me to gain money. **Third**, I live in the Middle-East. So *R&D departments* or *technical consultancy firms* in my region are not promising. So, I thought of working online.

After a little-bit of research, I guessed *cryptocurrency mining* is my best investment. It could be done online, requires mathematical skills, and funded.

I am well aware that my job request is nearly in-achievable to find. I am not asking to suggest me a magic solution that would give me everything. I am just seeking advice and consulting my community.

You could for instance advice me, **(1)** What academics do to gain more additional money, **(2)** What accessible career pathways I could gain money from, whose future is promising for a math enthusiast?, **(3)** What are the best opportunities to achieve something of a value in my CV, Even if it is not payed?

However, Feel free to give me any advice you believe is helpful.

Sincerely,

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good fit for this site, which is more geared toward technical questions. There's [academia.se], but I'm not sure it's spot-on there either.

Comment: It's an interesting question indeed, but not suitable for the site. In fact, I fear it might be not a good fit for any SE site as it's answer won't be objective but I might be wrong.